# Fill a Matrix (2d array) recursively in Java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a Java programming assignment to do and in one of the questions, I have to fill a boolean 2d array (matrix) with "false" everywhere. I did it using two loops as following:

```
// The length and width are given

boolean [][] matrix; 
matrix = new boolean [length][width];

int row;
int col;

for (row = 0; row < length; row++)
{
   for (col = 0; col < width; col++)
   {
      matrix[row][col] = false;
   }
}
```

The thing is that we just started the recursion chapter, and I would like if there is a way to do the same thing but this time using only recursion...
Thank you!

Comment: There are times when recursion isn't necessarily the right answer.  Have you talked with your instructor about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mimic the nested loop structure with recursion:

```
public static void fillWithFalse(boolean[][] array, int row) {
    if (row < array.length) {
        fillWithFalse(array[row], 0);
        fillWithFalse(array, row + 1);
    }
}

public static void fillWithFalse(boolean[] array, int col) {
    if (col < array.length) {
        array[col] = false;
        fillWithFalse(array, col + 1);
    }
}
```

or

```
public static void fillWithFalse(boolean[][] array, int row, int col) {
    if (row < array.length) {
        if (col < array[row].length) {
            array[row][col] = false;
            fillWithFalse(array, row, col + 1);
        } else {
            fillWithFalse(array, row + 1, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Which is identical logic. But recursion is not good for this kind of thing and also to fill an array with false the correct solution is this:

```
boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[length][width];
```

Because boolean arrays will be default initialized with all elements as false. If the assignment is literally to fill a boolean array with false it may be basically a trick question because no action is necessary except to instantiate the array.

Comment: Cool! that's exactly what I needed!
Actually I didn't know that boolean arrays are by default initialized  with false as all elements. I learned a new thing today!... Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. And indeed they are. All instance variables and array elements are initialized with default values. Objects are null, booleans are false, chars are a null character and number types are 0.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure why is it necessary.. but.. here's my solution:

```
public static void insertFalse(boolean [][] arr,int row,int column)
{
    if(row == 0&&column==0)
        return ;
    arr[row][column] = false;
    if(column == 0)
          insertFalse(arr,row-1,arr[0].length-1);
    else
        insertFalse(arr, row, column-1);
}
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work on account of the return condition. If you change false to true you'll see arr[0][0] is unchanged. The reason it perhaps appears to work is all elements in the array were false to begin with. It also assumes all the arrays are the same length which is not required in Java.

Comment: Radiodef, I filled the array with 'true' to check if it works, about the second part you said, I learned new things now too, thanks.